# Place two images on top of each other in a flex-box container

Tags: html, css

I have two images I want to place on top of each-other e.g a product (inner) and a "discount"-banner (outer).

Currently I have the image in an `a`-tag where the `a`-tag is a flex-box container such that I can use `align-items` and `justify-content`.

My HTML is the following

```css
.image-wrapper {
    height: 50%;
    margin-top:20px;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.image-wrapper a{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.image-wrapper img{
    width: auto;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-wrapper">

      <a href="{{p.link}}" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
        <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/9R1yfiOspfOVdrip4b4kF5i1cCaJWmdyKRJbtXw6bnmXiPqYRLZyUYYJL3MwiRWay8JjDNmdT8cpgxB7pBgWdLz04s6mjEYDE-DD5btDasFt7j-KPraA0YIFiF2rN2kSq9uq0PYNHc46NVmEokNuc1GbhujtP_NKyg72rnM" alt="Image of product" /></a>
      
      <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/9R1yfiOspfOVdrip4b4kF5i1cCaJWmdyKRJbtXw6bnmXiPqYRLZyUYYJL3MwiRWay8JjDNmdT8cpgxB7pBgWdLz04s6mjEYDE-DD5btDasFt7j-KPraA0YIFiF2rN2kSq9uq0PYNHc46NVmEokNuc1GbhujtP_NKyg72rnM" alt="Discount-banner" />

</div>
```

I would prefer still having the image in the a-tag, but if that cannot be done, it's fine (first priority is to have the two images on top of each-other)

Answer (score 0):

Put your second image inside a div, and apply the same CSS as your `a` tag to have both of them centered

```css
.image-wrapper {
  height: 50%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.image-wrapper a,
.image-wrapper div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.image-wrapper img {
  width: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-wrapper">

  <a href="{{p.link}}" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
    <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/9R1yfiOspfOVdrip4b4kF5i1cCaJWmdyKRJbtXw6bnmXiPqYRLZyUYYJL3MwiRWay8JjDNmdT8cpgxB7pBgWdLz04s6mjEYDE-DD5btDasFt7j-KPraA0YIFiF2rN2kSq9uq0PYNHc46NVmEokNuc1GbhujtP_NKyg72rnM" alt="Image of product" /></a>

  <div>
    <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/9R1yfiOspfOVdrip4b4kF5i1cCaJWmdyKRJbtXw6bnmXiPqYRLZyUYYJL3MwiRWay8JjDNmdT8cpgxB7pBgWdLz04s6mjEYDE-DD5btDasFt7j-KPraA0YIFiF2rN2kSq9uq0PYNHc46NVmEokNuc1GbhujtP_NKyg72rnM" alt="Discount-banner" />
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: This seems to place them next to each-other

Answer (score 0):

To overlay the second image over the first, you can use `position: absolute`

```css
.image-wrapper {
  height: 50%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.image-wrapper a {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.image-wrapper img {
  width: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.image-wrapper .overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="image-wrapper">

  <a href="{{p.link}}" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/300" alt="Image of product" />
    <img class="overlay" src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" alt="Discount-banner" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: This does not seem to work when having multiuple images that needs the discount-banner. ALl the banners are at the same place i.e in the middle of the screen

Comment: Did you add `position: relative` on the <a/> tag?